# I try javascript a game simon, how to do it if the level 5 game is finished

Tags: javascript

the program is running, I want if it reaches level 5 the game ends.
this project : https://codepen.io/alfiansyah/pen/bPbZjj

```
    if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
        if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                nextSequence();
            }, 1000);
        }
    } else {
        playSound("wrong");
        $("body").addClass("game-over");
        $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("body").removeClass("game-over");
        }, 200);

        startOver();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
  if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
    if (gamePattern.length < 5) { // Check level
      setTimeout(function() {
        nextSequence();
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      // Level 5 reached
    }
  }
} else {
[...]
```